# how to write a regex that has substring match and exclude another substring

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to evaluate 12 character strings, a sample string is a02016ab-B30, I want to find all strings that have 4 to 6 character as 016 and 10 to 11 character not as B3.

`.{3}(061).{3}(?!B3)` doesn't exclude string with more than 12 characters? how can I refine it?

Comment: The string is unachored and matches 9 chars. Should 061 be 016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^.{3}061.{3}(?!B3).{3}$
```

Or, if you have `016` after the first three chars:

```
^.{3}016.{3}(?!B3).{3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U6RtYk/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.{3}` - any three chars other than line break chars
- `061` - a substring
- `.{3}` - any three chars other than line break chars
- `(?!B3)` - `B3` substring is not allowed at the current location
- `.{3}` - any three chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was an easy fix!